# HTML button with background is not shown in IE8

Tags: html, css

My buttons in IE8 cant be shown, maybe you know why ? Tryed adding background: transparent url('..'), but didnt helped. This is the code:

```
.wpcf7 input.wpcf7-submit {
    background: url("/wp-content/themes/ASC/images/<?=ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;?>_submit.png") no-repeat scroll center top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0 none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 25px 0 0;
}

button,
input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-color: #ccc #ccc #bbb #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 black;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    cursor: pointer; /* Improves usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type 'input' and others */
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* Corrects inability to style clickable 'input' types in iOS */
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: .6em 1em .4em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

Comment: Don't tell me this is in an actual CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've specified an `rgba` colour value. IE8 doesn't recognise this, so it ignore the entire property.

Use transparent *instead* of the explicit colour (you can't have two colours)

```
background: transparent url("/wp-content/themes/ASC/images/<?=ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;?>_submit.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you still want to use rgba colour value in other browsers you can specify new style which is only for internet explorer

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

or

As Quentin's answer you can just change rgba to hex colour and give some transparency

Comment: There's no need to resort to browser detection to have an [rgba fallback](http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/alpha-colour/). And my answer does not suggest using opacity.

Comment: most of the problems will be solved by creating internet explorer only style sheet. That's why I gave this answer and yeah opacity is for the full layer, it was my bad

Comment: I'm quite happily using translucency, flexbox and other newish CSS features and having it gracefully degrade in IE8 without needing a separate stylesheet for it.